# Comparing 2 json files using phyton and outputting the difference in new output file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to compare 2 json files to do a delta check between them.

Exising json:

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "customer_id": "abc123",
      "id": "1",      
    },
    {
      "customer_id": "xyz456",
      "id": "2",
    }
 ]
}
```

Updated json:

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "customer_id": "abc123",
      "id": "1",      
    },
    {
      "customer_id": "def456",
      "id": "3",
    },
    {
      "customer_id": "xyz789",
      "id": "2",
    }
 ]
}
```

What i want is my code to get the new objects from the new json(in this case id:3 and customer id def456)

however i also want to keep the original existing values (id:2 customer id should remain as xyz456 instead of updated to the new value xyz789)

Here is my current code:

```
import json 

# Opening JSON file 

f = open('1.json',) 
y = open('2.json',)

# returns JSON object as a dictionary 

less_data = json.load(f)
more_data = json.load(y)

# Iterating through the json list 

for x in more_data['rules']:
   for y in less_data['rules']:
    if x['id']== y['id']:
     print("x:" + x['id'],"y:" + y['id'])
     break   
    print(x['id'] + " is not found")
    //take action to add in new objects into json output
```

running the program i get the following output:

x:1 y:1

1 is found

x:3 y:1

3 is not found

x:3 y:2

3 is not found

x:2 y:1

2 is not found

x:2 y:2

2 is found

I only want 3 is not found to be printed once after running till the end of the inner for loop instead of printing it out every iteration. Any help would be appreaciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try flatten the JSON & compare its keys as dict\json datatype is unordered kind of datatype:

**If you list ordering matters**

```
import collections
from itertools import chain

def flatten(d, parent_key='', sep='__'):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for idx, value in enumerate(v):
                items.extend(flatten(value, new_key + sep + str(idx), sep).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)

a1 = {'rules': [{'customer_id': 'abc123', 'id': '1'}, {'customer_id': 'xyz456', 'id': '2'}]}

a2 = {'rules': [{'customer_id': 'abc123', 'id': '1'}, {'customer_id': 'def456', 'id': '3'}, {'customer_id': 'xyz789', 'id': '2'}]}

flatten_a1 = flatten(a1)
flatten_a2 = flatten(a2)

print(flatten_a1)
print(flatten_a2)
```

Output:

```
>>> flatten_a1 => {'rules__0__customer_id': 'abc123', 'rules__0__id': '1', 'rules__1__customer_id': 'xyz456', 'rules__1__id': '2'}
>>> flatten_a2 => {'rules__0__customer_id': 'abc123', 'rules__0__id': '1', 'rules__1__customer_id': 'def456', 'rules__1__id': '3', 'rules__2__customer_id': 'xyz789', 'rules__2__id': '2'}
```

from `flatten_a1` & `flatten_a2` value, you can easily find the differences as data structure comes in single level (i.e. not in nested format)
You can find:

- which keys are missing
- keys are present but values are different